# Loading a movie clip in Flash CS5.5

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

could someone with a bigger brain give me a clue as to how I should approach this - I'm loading a movieclip into an empty movieclip on the stage and what I want is for the clip to 'zoom up' to 100% ( from say 30% size ).

I have been trying along these lines ( script attached to empty movieclip) :

```
onClipEvent(load) {
  scaleAmt = 10;
  this._alpha = 0;
  x = stage.width/2;
  y = stage.width/2;
}

onClipEvent(enterFrame) {
  if (scaleAmt < 100) {
     scaleAmt += 5;
     this._xscale = scaleAmt;
     this._yscale = scaleAmt;
     this._x = x;
     this._y = y;   

     if (this._alpha < 100) {
         this._alpha += 5;
     }
  }
}
```

This nearly does it, but the clip loading in scales from the left to right - I want it to scale up centrally?

Thanks for all suggestions :-)

Jim

Comment: Sorry - I can't get the hang of that code enter thingy

Answer (score 1):

If the clip is scaling in a given direction then you need to alter the registration point of your MovieClip so that it is in the centre of the graphics.

To do this, double click the MovieClip to view its contents and then move all of what you can select so that the little black `+` is in the middle of your selection.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marty - I did try that and it didn't appear to make any difference but I'll double check it and try again - thanks for your time in responding, much appreciated :-)